# Eclipse code birdview plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, preview

I wonder, if there is an Eclipse plugin for code birdview (preview, visualization, minimap, however it may be called)? I mean, when you see your code in a small preview window and may scroll using this window. Wait, I'll show you...

[image: Screenshot (taken from Sublime Text)]

Like this. (See the column, where the white rectangle is).

Comment: +1: Nice question. Which app are you using at the screenshot?

Comment: It is [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I saw this question again today, and found someone working on such a plugin on github. I have no idea how far progressed this project is, but it may be worth checking out:

https://github.com/apauzies/eclipse-minimap-view
[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's a "beta" version right now, there is still some issues to fix: some lag when you scroll and it doesn't display the full file if it doesn't fit in the minimap window.
I'll try to improve that!

Comment: @AlexandrePauzies any luck on tackling the improvements?

Comment: @DanielSokolowski Unfortunately no, didn't get time to work on this.

Answer (score 18):

[Here is "Overview" plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/687236) from a deleted by a mod answer that provides a minimap view.

[image]

*(I don't see a reason for deletion, it's exactly what OP asked for).*

Comment: I think this is better than the `eclipse-minimap-view` plugin. I have used them both and this one had fewer problems and better features like scaling.

Comment: As of March 2016, looks like this plugin is not only maintained but en route to be included in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Minimap is now present in Eclipse starting version 4.9
[Official link to the feature](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/platform.php#minimap)